# How to use tailwind to create a grid like structure with flex

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

`flex flex-wrap w-full py-0 px-8 pb-12 content-stretch justify-between` - these are the current tailwind classes I am using on the container div that wraps around the elements. All the elements are the same width and I want them to wrap to the next line when they cannot fit on the line. I want spacing between them to be equal (hence justify-between) but at the moment all I get is this:

[image]

I want to get this:

[image]

Comment: `flex flex-wrap` is enough

Comment: but if you just use flex and flex-wrap then there isn't responsive spacing between the elements

Comment: the spacings between the elements inside `flex flex-wrap` is depend on the style for the inside elements not the container's style. example: `<div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-2 sm:-mx-2 md:-mx-4 lg:-mx-8"><span class="mx-2 sm:mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8">A</span><span class="mx-2 sm:mx-2 md:mx-4 lg:mx-8">B</span></div>`

Comment: I knew that but thought that with adding :after on the container with flex: auto and content:"" we could get the correct result but then the spacing of the second last element to the last element is removed

Comment: I guess I will just use grid then, seems better for my instance

Comment: hi, let me know your full html code to get more easily :)

Comment: You can use `gap` (e.g. `gap-4`) with `flex flex-wrap` to add padding between your elements.